# How do I get an album's cover art in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Before anyone points it out, yes, I know there have been similar questions asked before. I've already tried solutions from them and they do not work, which is why I'm asking this question.

For reference, I'm using Android API 30.

So I'm performing a query on all audio files on the device using `MediaStore`. As of now I'm able to properly access artist/album/song IDs, names, etc. and use them elsewhere in my app. The one thing I'm unable to get though is the album art.

This is what my code looks like:

```cs
string[] columns = {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.IsMusic,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Title,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.CdTrackNumber,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Duration,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Album,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.AlbumId,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Artist,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.ArtistId,
};

ICursor? cursor = context.ContentResolver?.Query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri!, columns, null, null, null);
if (cursor is null)
{
    return;
}
while (cursor.MoveToNext())
{
    if (cursor.GetString(0) is not "1")
    {
        continue;
    }

    string trackPath = cursor.GetString(1)!;
    string trackTitle = cursor.GetString(2)!;
    int trackIndex = cursor.GetInt(3);
    uint trackDuration = (uint)(cursor.GetFloat(4) / 1000);
    long trackId = cursor.GetLong(5);
    string albumTitle = cursor.GetString(6)!;
    long albumId = cursor.GetLong(7);
    string artistName = cursor.GetString(8)!;
    long artistId = cursor.GetLong(9);
```

I initially tried the obvious method, which was adding `MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.AlbumArt` to `columns` and getting the data from that column. But just adding that causes the application to freeze. Logging shows that adding it causes the method to freeze midway and not do anything. So this solution is out.

I then tried `MediaMetadataRetriever`, like this:

```cs
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new();
retriever.SetDataSource(trackPath);
byte[] artwork = retriever.GetEmbeddedPicture()!;
Bitmap albumArt = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(artwork, 0, artwork.Length)!;
```

However, this also fails. I get an error message in the logs saying that `MediaMetadataRetriever` was unable to set the data source to that source.

So I figured maybe my data source was wrong. After doing some digging around I tried using a different path:

```cs
Uri contentUri = Uri.Parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")!;
Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(contentUri, albumId);

MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new();
retriever.SetDataSource(albumArtUri.Path);
...
```

This also does not work. Neither does using `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ExternalContentUri`.

I even tried opening a `ParcelFileDescriptor` from those URIs. Also doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a way that would definitely work? Most of the answers on StackOverflow seem to be quite dated, so they possibly don't apply to API 30 anymore. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong since the documentation isn't very detailed.

Comment: I found a lot of relevant looking hits with this query - https://www.google.com/search?q=android+album+art+api+30+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason thank you. One of those worked for me. Turns out I needed to wrap the whole thing in a `try/catch` statement to prevent it from freezing the application for some reason.